# RegEx for matching an alphanumeric pattern with quantifier

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to limit the digits between 4 and 6 in my regex but it is not working

Minimum range works but the max range does not work:

- `Some Text-1`  = validates
- `Some Text-201901` = validates
- `Some Text-20190101` = passes the validation where it should fail

Now if I add $ at the end then none of the above work.

Code:

```
^[A-Z ]{3,}-\d{4,6}
```

Comment: Add `$` at the end

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew he mentions that this exact solution doesn't work

Comment: That makes sense only if the regex is used in .NET with multiline flag and line endings are CRLF (and then it is a dupe of another question, `\r?$` should be used). Adding `$` generally fixes it, so it is closed correctly.

Comment: @Faisal where do you use this regex? can you add some code? Preferably a [mcve]

Comment: Use `^[A-Z ]{3,}-\d{4,6}(?!\d)`

Comment: Why does `Some Text-1` validate as there is only 1 digit?

Comment: Hi All: Thank you for all of your suggestions . Finally what worked was @sln solution ^[A-Z ]{3,}-[0-9]{3,6}(?!\d) .  What does (?!/d) do?

Comment: @CássioRenan I am using this regex in my c# code.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew \r?$ did not work

Comment: That means you do not want to match the whole string, but a substring at the beginning of a string that is not followed with a digit (the last 4 to 6 digits cannot be followed with a digit). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56401231/3832970).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ty for the explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use

```
^[A-Z ]{3,}-[0-9]{3,6}(?!\d)
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of a string
- `[A-Z ]{3,}` - three or more uppercase letters or spaces
- `-` - a hyphen
- `[0-9]{3,6}` - three to six digits
- `(?!\d)` - a [**negative lookahead**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location, there is a digit.

Comment: Ty for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure, what we might wish to pass and fail, however based on your original expression my guess is that this might be what we might want to start with with an `i` flag:

```
^[A-Z ]{3,}-\d{1,6}$
```

or without `i` flag:

```
^[A-Za-z ]{3,}-\d{1,6}$
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Tb5Me7/1/)

#### Test

```js
const regex = /^[A-Z ]{3,}-\d{1,6}$/gmi;
const str = `Some Text-1
Some Text-201901
Some Text-20190101`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired, it can be modified/changed in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Tb5Me7/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]